# Why doesn't the FireBug profiler stop running?

Tags: javascript, profiling, firebug

I am running the FireBug profiler on this code:

```
function y() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var x = i;
    }
}
console.profile();
y();
console.profileEnd();
```

However, it continuously says: "The profiler is running. Click 'profile' again to see its report."

Nothing happens when I click that message OR the Profile button.

Comment: I get [`No activity to profile`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5MzY4/). How should we reproduce your example?

Comment: I apologize, I truly was getting "The profiler is running..." with that example in jsFiddle - apparently restarting my system worked.  I've replaced my example with a version that works.

Comment: @sdasdadas It is highly doubtful that it was necessary to restart your entire computer. Did you *just* install Firebug, without having restarted the browser? Did you try clearing your cache? At any rate, voting to close as too localized.

Comment: No I've had Firebug installed forever.  I didn't try clearing my cache.  I can understand the vote to close but the fact is that there doesn't exist an answer to this question on StackOverflow.  For that reason, I think that it should be left open until a better answer appears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, this is solved by a system restart.  I am not sure what caused it to work forever.